# how to drag and drop table, combobox , radio button , textfield and textarea from toolbar to textpane in java?

Tags: java

I want that when i click on button on toolbar like a button for table then I drag from there and drop in TextPane .Likewise buttons for Combobox , Textfield and so on is given on toolbar

Comment: What have to tried so far? Please share your current work (not all of it, only the important lines!) by editing your question so it is easier for the community to help you. And consider to explain your problem in detail as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
public class after_create_resume_button 
{
     JButton cut,copy,paste,table;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new after_create_resume_button();
    }
    public after_create_resume_button() 
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try 
                {
                     UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                }
                catch(Exception ex) 
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Resume Maker");
                frame.setLayout(null);
                JToolBar jt=new JToolBar(); //in Toolbar cut,copy,paste,table,TextField
                cut=new JButton(new ImageIcon("D://final_project//Space1//img//cut.png"));
                copy=new JButton(new ImageIcon("D://final_project//Space1//img//copy.png"));
                paste=new JButton(new ImageIcon("D://final_project//Space1//img//paste.png"));
                table=new JButton(new ImageIcon("D://final_project//Space1//img//table.png"));
                JTextField jtf= new JTextField("Text field");
               // jtf.setBounds(0,0,50,50);
                cut.setToolTipText("Cut");
                copy.setToolTipText("Copy");
                paste.setToolTipText("Paste");
                table.setToolTipText("Table");
                jtf.setToolTipText("TextField");
                jtf.setEditable(false);
                jt.add(cut);
                jt.add(copy);jt.addSeparator();
                jt.add(paste);jt.addSeparator();
                jt.add(table);
                jt.addSeparator();
                jt.add(jtf);
               jt.setBounds(0,0,600,50);
               jt.setFloatable(false);
               jt.setRollover(true);

                frame.add(jt);

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                frame.add(new after_create_resume_buttonPane());

                frame.setSize(900, 900);

                frame.setResizable(false);

                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    public class after_create_resume_buttonPane extends JPanel 
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public after_create_resume_buttonPane() 
        {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();
            Document doc = tp.getDocument();
            try 
            {
                tp.insertComponent(new JTextField("Hello world"));
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\n", null);
                tp.insertComponent(new JComboBox(new String[]{"Banana", "Apple", "Grape"}));
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\n", null);
                tp.insertComponent(new JRadioButton("Option A"));
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\n", null);
                tp.insertComponent(new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(10, 5)));
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\n", null);
            }
            catch (BadLocationException exp) 
            {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
            setLocation(200,50);

            setSize(595, 842);

           // add(new JScrollPane(tp));

            add(tp);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please use the **Post Your Answer** button only for actual answers. You should [edit] your original post to add additional information.